# Fibonacci sequence, prove by induction that $a_{2n} \leq 3^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let ${a_n}$ be the Fibonacci sequence.  Prove by induction that $a_{2n} \leq 3^n$ (the Fibonacci sequence is defined as $a_1=1$, $a_2 = 2$, and $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$.)

**What I know**

- $3 \leq a_{2k-2} \leq 3^k $
- We need to prove that $a_{2k+2} \leq 3^{k+1} $

Comment: $\leq$ = `\le` or `\leq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sequence is increasing, so that
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} < 2 a_{n-1} \qquad (*)$$

Now, once you've established the induction hypothesis $a_{2k} \le 3^k$ for some $k$, simply expand $a_{2(k+1)}$ by the definition:
$$a_{2k+2} = a_{2k+1} + a_{2k}$$

Apply $(*)$ to one of the terms, and then invoke the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I really wish I could say it helped.  I just don't understand where this really gets me.

Comment: @ChrisCrutchfield: What does $(*)$ tell you about $a_{2k+1}$? (Take $n$ to be $2k+1$.)

Comment: Thank you, but I guess I am still confused.  By plugging in, I get that $a_{2k+1} = a_{2k} + a_{2k-1} < 2a_{2k} $, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: @ChrisCrutchfield: Okay, so back in the bottom equation, you now know $$a_{2k+2} < 2a_{2k} + a_{2k}$$ What's a better way to write the right-hand side?

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose $a_k \leq 3^{k/2}$ for all $k<n$, then $$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} \leq 3^{n/2-1/2}+3^{n/2-1} = 3^{n/2-1}\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)<3^{n/2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I follow until you state that $a_n \leq 3^{n/2 - 1/2}$.  Can you explain?

Comment: $a_{n-1}\leq 3^{n/2-1/2}$ and $a_{n-2}\leq 3^{n/2-1}$ by the induction hypothesis. I don't think I ever use $a_n\leq 3^{n/2-1/2}$.

Comment: I misread your answer, I'm still not really sure where to go with this.

Comment: @Abel: $a_{2k} \le 3^k$ does not imply $a_{k} \le 3^{k/2}$. (Consider the constant sequence $a_n = 3$, and $k=1$. Certainly $a_{2k} = a_2 = 3 \le 3^{k}$, but $a_{k} = a_1 = 3 \not\le \sqrt{3} = 3^{k/2}$.)

Comment: @Blue. You're right. I suggest proving $a_k \leq 3^{k/2}$ for all $k$ by induction. The OP's proposition then follows immediately by only considering even $k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary results:** In the middle of the proof, we will need to appeal to the fact that $a_m\le a_{m+1}$ for all $m$. We take care of that first.

**Lemma $1$:** For any $n\ge 1$, we have $a_n\ge 0$.

Proof of Lemma $1$: By induction. The result is true at $n=1$ and $n=2$. If it is true at $n=k-1$ and $n=k$, then it is true at $n=k+1$, since $a_{k+1}=a_k+a_{k-1}$.

**Lemma $2$:** For any $m\ge 1$, we have $a_{m+1}\ge a_m$.

Proof of Lemma $2$: This is true for  $m=1$. For $m\gt 1$, it follows from the fact that $a_{m+1}=a_m+a_{m-1}$ and $a_{m-1}\ge 0%.

**Main Proof:** The result is true at $n=1$. We show that if the result is true at $n=k$, then it is true at $n=k+1$.

So we know, for a particular $k$, that $a_{2k}\le 3^k$. We want to show that $a_{2k+2}\le 3^{k+1}$. Note that
$$a_{2k+2}=a_{2k+1}+a_{2k}=(a_{2k}+a_{2k-1})+a_{2k}=2a_{2k}+a_{2k-1}.\tag{1}$$
Note that by Lemma $2$, we have $a_{2k-1}\le a_{2k}$. So from Equation (1) we conclude that
$$a_{2k+2}\le 3a_{2k}.$$
Since $a_{2k}\le 3^k$, it follows that $a_{2k+2}\le 3\cdot 3^k=3^{k+1}$. This completes the induction step.